Find the revision in the git during bisecting
I'm trying to find what commit broke my project. It is cross-platform software.
I started bisection, but unfortunately I hit the merge commit where I merge changes from another machine which runs different OS. (I'm bisection on Windows and merging changes from Linux).
Unfortunately the changes i merged introduce compilation errors on Windows.
I just tried to run git log but the first commit shown there is from. The HEAD and not the master.
How do I deal with this situations?
It would be nice if i can look at the history, run the diff and apply it temporary, but i can't do that, since I don't see the commits further than the current bisect HEAD.
What is the best course of action here?

@eftshift0, Can you elaborate please? What do I do with that commit on Linux machine is irrelevant. I'm doing bisecting on Windows and am looking for to get the commit ahead of the current where all errors are fixed...

I thought the problem was that you needed to see if the commit was good/bad and it would work on a different arch ... Let me read it more thoroughly

On... So you run git log  and it's not master history.... Sure, you are in the middle of a bisect so HEAD is not on master..... You can just as easily (with a little more typing) write git log master and get master's history..... I am not sure what is the problem or what you would like to do now.

If there is a later commit that solves some problem you are facing so that you can continue bisecting, you can do: git show some-random-commit | git apply - to apply temporarily. Then to remove it: git show some-random-commit | git apply -r - so you can continue bisecting.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_avoiding_testing_a_commit <- if you can't tell if a commit is good or bad (or is bad for all the wrong reasons), you can select a different commit to try, or you can git bisect skip and have git select one for you.

@teapot418, What will git bisect skip do? Will it go to the next one in history?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/36497937/21105992 <- allegedly it will choose a random one

@teapot418, since it is randomly selected - I'd rather choose the very next commit on master branch. That way I will know what will happen with bisection. I will go skip route only if it's not possible...

@eftshift0, What is this <some_random_commit>?

<some_random_commit> = "a later commit that solves a problem you are facing (on the commit you are currently on)"

@eftshift0, and how do I find put ths commit SHA? git log doesn't shpw anything after the current HEAD, because I', in the midle of the bisecting...

Try git log <name-of-branch> or gitk --all or git bisect visualize.

I already addressed that question in a previous comment.

@KarlKnechtel, not even close I do know how to do bisecting. I also familiar how to run git log to find the revision. However, what I don't know is how to mix them  and this is what the question is about. If you can tell it  - sorry.
